# function with loop to include significance code

Tags: function, loops

I would like to create a function that uses the input matrix and puts significance codes (*; **; ***) besides the values in the matrix.

significance<-function(x){

for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {

for (j in 1:nrow(x)) {

paste(round(x[j,i], digits=4)

if (x[j,i]>2.58) {"***"}

else if (x[j,i]>1.96 {"**"}

else if (x[j,i]>1.645 {"*"} {""}, sep = "")

else if (x[j,i]>1.96) {"**"}

else if (x[j,i]>1.645) {"*"}

else if (x[j,i]<1.645) {""}, sep = "")

}}}

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The function I posted is not working, can anyone figure out why?